# Fontsize of Contextmenu

Tags: android, themes

I spend now some time in trying to change the textsize of the contextmenu. I searched the sdk's themes.xml and styles.xml and tried a lot but didn't succeed in actually resizing the text.

Anyone knows how to do it?

Cheers!

Nob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No
Long answer: Why don't you create your custom dialog that looks like the ContextMenu? It's so easy to create a custom dialog in this way.

For an example to this, 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

go look at "Add a list" section.

Comment: thanks for the proposition. that would be indeed a solution. The more as I already used themed dialogs. But isn't it a bit like cracking a nut with a sledgehammer?

Comment: It's all up to you(maybe) to decide if you really need that font size to be changed. Your right. It may be a bit crazy to reinvent the wheel. In all my apps, I would prefer flex over stock driven. If you think this would create a bit pain on you, just to see if you can make a library to create this function. I always do. :)

Comment: mmhh. probably, I will do it like that. I was just wondering, if there is no other way, because almost everything can be changed by the theme.xml file

Comment: After diggin into the source code: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/com/android/internal/view/menu/IconMenuItemView.java.htm

I dont think it would be easy to change.

But I found this post, http://www.techjini.com/blog/2011/04/19/customizing-background-and-text-color-in-options-menu-android/

You may try to see if you can do the same on the ContextMenu. If that's what you want.